# Concurrent transactions visibility in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, isolation-level

I have a Hibernate 3.6 + MySQL setup and I want to examine it for concurrent transactions:

```
package hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

import org.hibernate.*;

public class HibernateGames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //first read of the entity
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Message loaded = (Message) session.load(Message.class, 21l);
        System.out.println(loaded.getText());

        //here goes the concurrent update:
        Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();
        Message loaded2 = (Message) session2.load(Message.class, 21l);
        loaded2.setText("Concurrent update!!!");
        tx2.commit();
        session2.close();

        //second read of the entity
        loaded = (Message) session.load(Message.class, 21l);
//        session.refresh(loaded); //refresh or not refresh the entity after concurrent update
        System.out.println(loaded.getText());
        session.close();

        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Here are my results and conclusions:

1. if MYSQL isolation level = REPEATABLE READ then second read cannot see the updated value even if refresh is enabled. The only way to see the fresh values is to start a new transaction, which means open another session.
2. if MYSQL isolation level = READ COMMITTED then second read can see the updated value only if refresh is enabled.
3. If there is no refresh, whatever happens, once the object or its proxy was loaded into persistent context during the session - it will never be updated in case of some concurrent changes to the underlying rows of database. Just because Hibernate will look in cache or use the proxy. This means that if you dont update the object manually you will never see uncommited,commited,repeatable or phantom reads in Hibernate, no matter which isolation level is set.

Is this correct?